# Keep getting -2147483647 as result

Tags: c#, recursion

For some reason the if else statement in my code returns -2147483647. Not sure why.  I used breakpoints and int.MaxValue is 2147483647.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int [] array = {1,2,3};
            int bigNumber = 5;
            Console.WriteLine(minNumber(bigNumber, array).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int minNumber(int bigNumber, int[] array)
        {
            int minNumberOCoins = int.MaxValue;

            if (bigNumber == 0) { return 0; }
            else if (bigNumber <= 0) { return minNumberOCoins; }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                int returnedNumbers = minNumber((bigNumber - array[i]), array) +1;
                if (returnedNumbers < minNumberOCoins)
                {
                    minNumberOCoins = returnedNumbers;
                }
            }

            return minNumberOCoins;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you take a debugger, put few breakpoints and see?

Comment: I used breakpoints and the debugger.  For some reason the else if statement returns the negative version of int.MaxValue

Comment: So what is that "some reason"? Does not degugger clarify that?

Comment: Adding `1` to `int.MaxValue` produces integer overflow, and then things get crazy. (I bet you didn't actually check the return value at the `else`; rather you checked the value of `returnedNumbers`, but that is not the value returned by the `else`; that is the value returned by the `else` *plus one*.)

Comment: @Aaron I've read the code a couple of times and I *really* don't understand what it's supposed to do. Could you please describe the expected behavior in plain words?

Comment: Adding on to what Raymond has said, you can add `checked` to you arithmetic expressions to get an exception and see exactly where you're getting integer overflow.

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your `for` loop, you are adding `1` to the result of a call to minNumber.
2. When bigNumber is less than zero, the method returns `int.MaxValue`
3. `int.MaxValue + 1 == int.MinValue`

I'll leave it to you to step through the code, but in the first loop, when `bigNumber` is `5`, you continue to do a recursive call, subtracting `array[0]` (which is `1`) from it. This continues until `bigNumber` is `0`, when the method call returns `int.MaxValue`. You then add `1` to it (which gives you `int.MinValue`), and then return this number (because it's less than `minNumberOCoins`).

If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish, we can help with a better algorithm.